# Is it possible to use Entity Framework Code First with existing databases that don't fully use EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

For example, we have a database A, which exists interoperates with apps that use the traditional approach of model first, stored procs, and ADODB access.

Then we have an EF5 CF project that comes along and wants to use the same database. Can the two co-exist peacefully?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a range of options for mapping Code First entities into pre-existing database schemes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg194005.aspx

Comment: It should be noted, however, that there are some kinds of data model schemes that may not translate well, and EF5 and less do not support using stored procs for Insert, update or delete (this is being added to EF6)

Comment: @GertArnold - Not for code first it wasn't. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap